# Lower bound on smallest principal angle between two complementary subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, svd, projection-matrices

Let $U, V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be two subspaces spanned by the columns of $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and $B = A + E$, respectively. Moreover, let $n = 2m$, $A$ and $B$ have full rank, and $U \cap V = 0$ i.e. $U+V=\mathbb{R}^n$. Are there any lower bounds on the smallest principal angle (Miao et al., 1992) or, equivalently, upper bounds on its cosine,
$$\cos(\theta_1)=\max_{\substack{u\in U, v\in V\\||u||=||v||=1}} u^\top v = ||P_U P_V||?$$
Here, $P_U, P_V$ denote the orthogonal projections onto $U$ and $V$ and $||\cdot||$ the spectral norm.

My attempt was to use that by Ipsen & Mayer (1995) the minimal angle $\theta_1$ between two complementary subspaces satisfies,
$$\sin(\theta_1) = \dfrac{1}{||(P_U-P_V)^{-1}||}.$$
Hence, it would suffice to have a lower bound on the minimum singular value of $P_U-P_V$. However, I have been somewhat struggling to find results on this in the literature.

Thanks in advance for any help!

##### References

*Miao, Jianming; Ben-Israel, Adi*, [**On principal angles between subspaces in (\mathbb{R}^n)**](https://doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795(92)90251-5), Linear Algebra Appl. 171, 81-98 (1992). [ZBL0779.15003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0779.15003).

*Sun, Jiguang*, Perturbation of angles between linear subspaces, J. Comput. Math. 5, 58-61 (1987). [ZBL0632.15009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0632.15009).

*Ipsen, Ilse C. F.; Meyer, Carl D.*, [**The angle between complementary subspaces**](https://doi.org/10.2307/2975268), Am. Math. Mon. 102, No. 10, 904-911 (1995). [ZBL0842.15002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0842.15002).

Comment: Do you mean you want a lower bound on the minimum $u^\top v$ for any two unit vectors $u\in U$ and $v\in V$?

Comment: No, an upper bound on $u^\top v$.

Comment: I think the smallest principal angle would be a minimum over $u$ and $v$, not a maximum. If you want an upper bound, then maybe you have several typos in the question and title.

Comment: @Tai Principal angles are defined as the $\arccos$ of the inner product of the principal vectors. It holds $0 \leq \theta_1 \leq ... \leq \theta_m\leq \pi/2$ and $1 \geq \cos(\theta_1) \geq ... \geq \cos(\theta_m)\geq 0$ since $\cos$ is strictly decreasing on $[0,\pi/2]$. So, a lower bound on the largest principal angle $\theta_1$ is equivalent to an upper bound on $\cos(\theta_1)$, because inner products are large if angles are small. For an overview of principal angles between subspaces please see [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379592902515).

Comment: I slightly modified the question to clarify and explain my attempt to get a lower bound. I hope that's alright.